Motivating the second derivative definition given in Audin,Damian Morse Theory text.
I am reading the Morse theory and Floer Homology text written by Audin and Damian.In the first chapter they have made a remark about second order derivatives on manifolds,the remark is quoted verbatim below:

Remark: Recall that a function on a manifold does not have a second order derivative,we can compute the second order derivative in a chart but it will depend on the choice of local coordinates.The second order derivative is well defined on the Kernel of the first order derivative.We will content ourselves with defining it at critical points.Rather that using a chart and showing that the result does not depend on it,we will define it more intrinsically.If $x$ is a critical point of $f$ and $X,Y\in T_xM$,then we set $d^2f_x(X,Y)=X.(\overline{Y}.f)(x)$ where $\overline Y$ is a vector field extending $Y$ locally.

I am interested in understanding(yet I haven't) why this is defined in this way and is it the most natural way to define this.Also other question is why are we taking $x$ to be a critical point of $f$ only,what would happen if we try to give the same definition for general points,whether regular or critical.
My Guess:
I think this definition is a generalization of the first order derivative definition in the sense that $df_x(X)=X(f)(x)$ is the definition for $X\in T_xM$.Thus from that perspective it is fine.But what if we want to understand the meaning of this physically?What is the connection between $d^2f_x$ and the so called $2$-jets?
Can someone please provide some insight or help in understanding why it is consistent with the definition given for Euclidean spaces $D^2f:U\to \operatorname{Bil}(\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$?

If $x$ is a critical point, then $X(Yf)-Y(Xf) = [X,Y]f$ vanishes at $x$, and the second order derivative as defined here at $x$ is symmetric
